# find a user/customer max count of continuous date using Python

Tags: python, date, dataframe

Scenario: I have a sample data frame like below

```
user_id | date_login
--------|-----------
101     | 2015-10-11
101     | 2015-10-12
101     | 2015-11-01
101     | 2015-11-02
101     | 2015-11-03
102     | 2015-10-12
102     | 2015-10-13
...
```

I would like to know user's max active days, which means the count of continuous days he/she keeps log into the system. For the sample data frame above, the desired result should return like below:

```
user_id | max_continuous_login_count
--------|-----------
101|3
102|2
```

I'm thinking to convert date into number to compare, is it necessary, any good practice?

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I've edited your question for formatting, but for future reference, when posting code samples, please be sure to format them properly. Precede each line of code by four spaces, or hit the button that looks like a `{}` in the toolbar. This will automatically format the code. If you want to put code inline, such as "I have a variable `foo`", write a backtick (the symbol below the tilde, ~, right below the esc key) before and after the code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
import operator
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce

dataset = [(101, "2015-10-11"), (101, "2015-10-12"), (102, "2015-10-13")]

data = defaultdict(list)

for user, date in dataset:
    data[user].append(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").date())
    data[user].sort()

def count_days(data, new_date):
    max_days, current_max, last_date = data
    # Check if there's one day difference, else, reset back to 1.
    if abs((new_date - last_date).days) != 1:
        current_max = 0
    current_max += 1
    return max(max_days, current_max), current_max, new_date

result = {}

for user, dates in data.items():
    result[user] = reduce(count_days, dates, (0, 0, datetime.date.min))[0]
```

What I did here, was to first convert the dataset into a dict mapping a user and his login dates. On the way, I converted the dates to date objects and sorted them in the correct order (just in case the dataset is garbled).

I then created a function `count_days()` which checks if the difference is 1 day between 2 dates. If it is, it increases the max count of days. Then, by using reduce, I created a new results dict mapping user id to max_days.

Comment: Many thanks @Bharel, I used a work around here, basically created a additional columns is_active(1=active, 0=inactive), and expand all dates for a user, thus a customers history will be like: 111000111101101, thus the max continuous day here is 4, I'm using following code to detect the longest 1111 as string and get its length: `lambda x: len(max(re.compile("(1+1)*").findall(''.join(map(str, x)))))` and again, I think your method is more desirable. Great help!!!